# TOC Fails to Insert Page Break when Vertical Spacing Between the Entries is Increased

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking, tocloft, vertical-spacing

Consider the MWE which contains the command `\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vspace*{5pt}}`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage  
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\large} 
\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vspace*{5pt}} 
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\dotfill}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{1. \textcolor{red}{\textbf{A rose by any other name would smell as sweet.}} A rose by any other name would smell as sweet. A rose by any other name would smell as sweet.}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{2. \textcolor{red}{\textbf{A rose by any other name would smell as sweet.}} A rose by any other name would smell as sweet. A rose by any other name would smell as sweet. A rose by any other name would smell as sweet.}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{3. \textcolor{red}{\textbf{A rose by any other name would smell as sweet.}} A rose by any other name would smell as sweet. A rose by any other name would smell as sweet. A rose by any other name would smell as sweet.}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{4. \textcolor{red}{\textbf{A rose by any other name would smell as sweet.}} A rose by any other name would smell as sweet. A rose by any other name would smell as sweet. A rose by any other name would smell as sweet.}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{5. \textcolor{red}{\textbf{A rose by any other name would smell as sweet.}} A rose by any other name would smell as sweet. A rose by any other name would smell as sweet. A rose by any other name would smell as sweet.}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{6. \textcolor{red}{\textbf{A rose by any other name would smell as sweet.}} A rose by any other name would smell as sweet. A rose by any other name would smell as sweet. A rose by any other name would smell as sweet.}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{7. \textcolor{red}{\textbf{A rose by any other name would smell as sweet.}} A rose by any other name would smell as sweet. A rose by any other name would smell as sweet. A rose by any other name would smell as sweet.}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{8. \textcolor{red}{\textbf{A rose by any other name would smell as sweet.}} A rose by any other name would smell as sweet. A rose by any other name would smell as sweet. A rose by any other name would smell as sweet.}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{9. \textcolor{red}{\textbf{A rose by any other name would smell as sweet.}} A rose by any other name would smell as sweet. A rose by any other name would smell as sweet. A rose by any other name would smell as sweet.}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{10. \textcolor{red}{\textbf{A rose by any other name would smell as sweet.}} A rose by any other name would smell as sweet. A rose by any other name would smell as sweet. A rose by any other name would smell as sweet.}
\end{document}
```

Which produces the Content output

[image]

**In addition to (1), failing to insert a page break---** there is also (for reasons unbeknownst to me) --- (2) a leading blank page just prior to the Contents, and (3) a header (which I did not call for) appearing on the Contents page displaying *CONTENTS*, as well as the page number.

I have noticed that if I remove the command `\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vspace*{5pt}}` from the Preamble, everything seems to be put back in good working order---i.e., the TOC inserts a page break at the appropriate place, the leading blank page disappears, and the mysterious header no longer exists.

QUESTION: Why does the use of `\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vspace*{5pt}}` seem to cause such havoc? How may I correct these anomalies while still increasing the vertical spacing between chapter entries an additional 5pt?

Thank you.

Comment: Use  `\vspace{5pt}` instead of `\vspace*{5pt}`. See  https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVSw6.jpg

Comment: The header will appear in the second page. The first uses a plain pagestyle.

Comment: @Simon Dispa Thank you. Offhand, do you know why `\vspace*` causes such problems whereas `\vspace`  does not?

Comment: @Simon Dispa Also, do you know why the header would appear at all? I did not call for it anywhere in the code. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: @mlchristians you certainly want vspace not vspace* as the latter is not dropped at a page break forcing an entry to be 5pt below the start of the page.

Comment: in book `\pagestyle{headings}` is the default page style except on chapter openings, so getting plain page style on the first page of the toc is expected

Comment: @David Carlisle Many thanks for your two comments.